# Can wisdom tooth cause hip ache?

Tags: hips, wisdom-teeth, cause-and-effect, referred-pain

I went to a doctor a few days ago for a chronic ache at the left hip. She performed some kinesiology tests on me and said that's the wisdom tooth position that influenced my hip and causes me pain. She suggested to do an x-ray and have it out if needed.

Is that even possible?

Comment: Not a doctor, but that sounds really strange. In the absence of other data I'd get a second opinion myself. Was kinesiology her area of expertise?

Comment: Kind of, she actually is a foot doctor but she attended the kinesiology school too.

Comment: Other than possible gait problems, why are you seeing a foot doctor for hip pain? There is such a thing as referred pain, but even that is a stretch.

Comment: I saw a foot doctor because my mum bought a special-priced appointment  and we found out that she wasn't only a foot doctor. By the way I saw other 5 or 6 doctors bot no one seems to find a solution. But this is OT

Comment: Well, as this was diagnosed by a doctor we can hardly be helpful here. Even if you did already, you may see another doctor to have some more professional advice.

Comment: (I read you have seen foot doctors, but have you seen a dentist?)

Comment: You should ask your foot doctor again why she thinks position of the wisdom tooth could cause the hip ache and please give more details, as this is something unusual.

Comment: @shlublu no, I have to do an x-ray first, but we're definetly going ot

Comment: Yes, you're right, sorry for having encouraged you to be off topic. Good luck with that anyway.

Comment: @kenorb kinesiology says that wisdom tooth is connected with iliopsoas, and wrong position tenses the muscle which in turn rotates the hip

Comment: @Phate01 - "Kinesiology" says? My first degree is in kinesiology, which is the study of human movement (kinetics). I'm not aware of anything connecting wisdom teeth with the iliacus and psoas major (iliopsoas is actually two muscles, although many refer to them as one since they are so closely related in structure and function). I am aware of some yoga type beliefs with the meridians, but that is very much a soft science and unproven.

Comment: I've created meta post: [Should acupuncture meridian questions be on topic?](http://meta.health.stackexchange.com/q/92/114) if that kind of questions should be on-topic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [human kinetics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kinesiology), the movements of [hip](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hip) muscles in hip joint are performed by a series of muscles.

For example, when hip is doing external rotation (30° with the hip extended, 50° with the hip flexed), it's using the gluteal muscles including [iliopsoas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iliopsoas) (combination of the [psoas major](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Psoas_major_muscle) and the [iliacus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iliacus_muscle) at their inferior ends).

According to [Meridian system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meridian_%28Chinese_medicine%29), these muscles help keep the lumbar curve in the spine and weakness on one side can cause the hip to drop or the foot to turn in on the affected side causing low back/pelvic pain or a problem with the ileocaecal valve.

For example, when a wisdom tooth is extracted (or possibly when it's in the wrong position), it usually forms a cavitation within the jawbone leaching toxins and causing a variety of chronic health consequences which can adversely affect the heart, small intestine, hormone production and further forming cavitations may cause problems with the large intestine or lung (See: [Dental Cavitations](http://www.thenaturalrecoveryplan.com/articles/Dental-Cavitations.html), video [1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cjnTZQoP-a8) & [2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KKg5IGJM_ao)). This may also relate to persistent or recurrent shoulder pain or weakness (due to subscapularis tension or laxity) which may be indirectly associated with the extraction site and an indicator of a heart issue.

Traditional Asian medicine has long maintained that every body part (ie: organs, tissues, glands, etc) is animated by a specific [acupuncture meridians](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meridian_%28Chinese_medicine%29) (pathways). All the meridians run through the teeth or their sockets and in this way each tooth is related to the rest of the body. The following chart explains that relationship:

[image: meridian tooth chart]

Which can help you to establish potential links between dental and systemic health issues.

This short [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yt6yQKxzw9U) explains how there is a two-way relationship such that stresses within the body can manifest in the mouth as toothache.

See also: [Muscles Associated With Meridians](http://www.thenaturalrecoveryplan.com/articles/Muscles-Associated-With-Meridians.html) and [The meridian system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meridian_%28Chinese_medicine%29) at Wikipedia.

I hope that helps.